# How can I filter using current data in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

I want to filter my result with current date but it doesn't work

1-

```
db.tickets.aggregate([
  {
    $project:{
      month:{
        $month:"$ticket.headerEntity.businessDate"},
        day:{
        $dayOfMonth:"$ticket.headerEntity.businessDate"},
        year:{ $year:"$ticket.headerEntity.businessDate"},
        day1:{ $dayOfMonth:"$currentDate" }
      }
    },
    { $match:{ month:4, day:day1 }
  }
])
```

2-

```
db.tickets.aggregate([
  {
    $project:{
      month:{
        $month:"$ticket.headerEntity.businessDate"
      },
      day:{ $dayOfMonth:"$ticket.headerEntity.businessDate" },
      year:{ $year:"$ticket.headerEntity.businessDate" }
    }
  },
  { 
    $match:{ 
      month:4, 
      day:{ "$dayOfMonth":"$currentDate" }
    }
  }
])
```

I have a tickets in my DB and I want to find the currentDate tickets .

Comment: please provide the details of your documents, at least one sample documents.

Answer (score 0):

Your first query just needs a little change:

```
{ $match:{ month:4, day:day1 } change this into:

{ $match:{ month:4, day:"$day1" }
```

The second query is correct, make sure there are documents that actually fit the query and that both fields are saved as a Date object and not as string.

Answer (score 0):

[`$currentDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/#up._S_currentDate) is an update operator, not an aggregation pipeline operator, so you need to get the current date client-side instead.

So instead of:

```
day: {"$dayOfMonth": "$currentDate"}
```

use:

```
day: (new Date()).getDate()
```